# Apple push notification without Apple Server

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

is there a possibility to send Push Notifications to iOS Clients without the use of Apple´s Server´s?!

And on the other Hand is it possible to push a whole file?! like a XML-File for example, or can you just push text messages?!

Another Question, is there any way to push an xml-file to an iOS Client remotely?!

Comment: No way, not possible.

Comment: Have you read the push notification documentation?!

Comment: can be done if application is running in the background using socket programming through VOIP. But if the application is not running(foreground or background) you will get nothing.

Comment: @Bhumeshwerkatre Which Question did you answer?

Comment: @chrizstone He answered about push notification, you definitively can't send push notification without Apple's servers.

Comment: Ahh ok, first Question solved...:) THX

Comment: @chrizstone I answered to your question only :)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can just push text message, sound (actually tell the system to play specific sound on a push, not the actual sound file). All these info are transferred in json format (push notification payload) with maximum size 256 byte and NO there is no way to do it without using Apple Push Notification System (apns).

On your second question you can push the xml file to your app using http request/response (when your app is running, not with push notification).

Comment: So i only get the xml-File when i start my App?!

Comment: Exactly. Or when your app comes to foreground.

Comment: sorry, but since ios7 thats not the true. in ios7 you can execute netrequests in background and even if the app is not runing at all. you can wake up the app with apns and then execute bgQueues to fetch the data from server, without any user side action.

Comment: @visualication you have very limited time to do it when the app is in background, and it is not done via push notifications. You are talking about background fetch, but the question is about transferring an xml file via push. Background fetch works only when the app is running in the background, push works even the app is killed completely. It is a completely different case.

Comment: no, again: since ios7 the limitation is canceled. and you can wakeup the app and can requests data from a server. it is as i wrote. see as example http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/ios-7-sdk-background-transfer-service/ or read the intro from ray wenderlich -> http://www.raywenderlich.com/51127/nsurlsession-tutorial

Comment: @visualication again: this requires that the app is running. The question asks about push which means having that functionality even when the app is not running in the background.

Comment: Nikos is right! If the App is completely killed you cannot background fetch anything! But is it possible to launch Safari as a background fetch?! For example, my App is running in Background, can i start Safari when a Push receives?!

Comment: hey guys, for all of you!!! try reading... from the NSURLSession class reference from apple: "This API provides a rich set of delegate methods for supporting authentication and gives your app the ability to perform background downloads when your app is not running or, in iOS, while your app is suspended." sometimes there are new things to learn... even if you think you're the guru ;-)

Comment: visualication is right guys. You can wake up a non-running app with a push notification in iOS 7, and then start a background fetch. See http://asciiwwdc.com/2013/sessions/204?q=push%20notification

Comment: Ok, i just read it! Aparently you can wake up a not running App! But how to do that?!

Answer (score 6):

Sorry no this is not possible. With Push notifications the Provider needs to send the notification to the APNS (Apple Push Notification Service) which will send it to the correct device.

This works like:

[image]

You are also not able to send files just notifications in the for of Text, sound etc. So no XML file via Push notifications sorry.

You could however do it were you notify the user through Push Notification that there is a file available and then download it when the app opens.

Check [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html) for more on Push Notifications